# Ubuntu 21.10 bluetooth not working after resuming from suspension. Only restart fixes it

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, bluetooth, bluez

When I suspend my machine and then I resume it, under both Ubuntu 21.10 and Pop!_OS 21.10, the bluetooth disappears, as shown in the following images:

[image]

[image]

It's like there is no bluetooth card in my pc. The only thing that fixes it is a restart.

Looking online this seems to be a common problem. I tried all the solutions I could find.

Some older post attributed the problem to an old buggy version of bluez, but on my machine I have the latest version:

```
gerardozinno@pop-os:~$ dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'
Version: 5.60-0ubuntu2.1
```

I tried the solution suggested here https://askubuntu.com/questions/875901/no-bluetooth-found-plug-in-a-dongle-to-use-bluetooth:

```
gerardozinno@pop-os:~$ rfkill list all
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

but my output, as opposed to the one in the post, shows no bluetooth.

After I tried the following solution found [here](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-no-bluetooth-found-plug-in-a-dongle-to-use-bluetooth-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts/):

```
gerardozinno@pop-os:~$ hcitool dev
Devices:

gerardozinno@pop-os:~$ sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
gerardozinno@pop-os:~$ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-01-04 22:46:57 CET; 8min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 40233 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18336)
     Memory: 544.0K
        CPU: 16ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─40233 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

gen 04 22:46:57 pop-os systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Deactivated successfully.
gen 04 22:46:57 pop-os systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
gen 04 22:46:57 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
gen 04 22:46:57 pop-os bluetoothd[40233]: Bluetooth daemon 5.60
gen 04 22:46:57 pop-os systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
gen 04 22:46:57 pop-os bluetoothd[40233]: Starting SDP server
gen 04 22:46:57 pop-os bluetoothd[40233]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 i>
```

from the output it seems to me that the bluetooth should be active and running, so where is the problem?

I also tried asking first on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385218/bluetooth-disappears-when-i-suspend-the-pc-or-close-the-lid), but since they are less technical over there I'm asking here too. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You might try some of the suggestions from https://askubuntu.com/questions/380096/turn-on-off-bluetooth-from-shell-not-from-applet , e.g., *systemctl restart bluetooth* or from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608116/bluetooth-wont-turn-on-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: @DrMoishePippik already tried, didn't work